# Include integer in message box

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

In my program, MatchAttempts is defined as an integer. How can i show a message box to the user and include whatever the value of MatchAttempts is

```
Dim MatchAttempts As integer = 0
```

How can i include the value of MatchAttempts in a message box?

Comment: matchAttempts.toString

Comment: @user1937198 i not agree the .toString method return a string from a integer :)

Comment: It was ninja-edited. The original question asked about when MatchAttempts had a value of `MessageBox.Show()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
MessageBox.Show(MatchAttempts.ToString)
```

Comment: thankyou, that works. It says I can accept your answer in 8 minutes so I'll do it then.